# Python: paramiko ImportError even after pip install

Tags: python, pip, paramiko

I would like to use a Python script on my Raspberry Pi 2 to upload a .txt file to my SFTP Webspace.

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload.py", line 1, in <module>
    import paramiko
ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

But I did this: `pip install paramiko`

This is my code:

```
import paramiko
import Crypto


# Open a transport

host = "HOST"
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

# Auth

password = "XXXX?"
username = "XXXX"
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)

# Go!

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

# Download

#filepath = '/var/www/xxx/test.txt'
#localpath = 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\test.txt'
#sftp.get(filepath, localpath)

# Upload 1

filepath = '/home/niklaspi/pythonupload'  #test ist in diesem Fall ein Ordner mit mehreren Dateien
localpath = '/home/pi/Desktop/Network/logs/logLocal.txt'
sftp.put(localfile, remfile)

# Close

sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: did the pip install work properly?

Comment: Yes - no error on this one.

Comment: so, if you just do an 'import paramiko' in python, does it work?

Comment: I created test.py with the "import paramiko" and in second line print('test') - same error

Comment: then probably paramiko is not installed properly or is not in your python path

Comment: what if you just type :`$ python -c "import paramiko;print paramiko.__version__"`

Comment: also try `$ locate paramiko.py`

Comment: Sorry my friend I am a total beginner and absolut new! I dont know really what to do there

Comment: Have you tried @JoranBeasley's suggestions? From the command line, type "python -c "import paramiko;print paramiko.__version__" and give us the result

Comment: Doing this locate stuff gives me: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ locate paramiko.py
-bash: locate: command not found

Comment: hmmm Im pretty sure locate was included in rasbian ... try running `sudo apt-get install mlocate` then `sudo updatedb` then do the locate command

Comment: Now when I run locate it gives me no answer but also no error: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo locate paramiko.py
pi@raspberrypi ~ $

Comment: did you run `updatedb`? if so that indicates that paramiko is not found anywhere in the system... are you sure that `pip install paramiko` succeeded without failure?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo pip install paramiko
Collecting paramiko
  Using cached paramiko-1.15.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ecdsa>=0.11 (from paramiko)
  Using cached ecdsa-0.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycrypto!=2.4,>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from paramiko)
Installing collected packages: ecdsa, paramiko


Successfully installed ecdsa-0.13 paramiko-1.15.2
pi@raspberrypi ~ $

Comment: guys you were right:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload.py", line 31, in <module>
    sftp.put(localfile, remfile)
NameError: name 'localfile' is not defined

Comment: import isnt the error anymore! thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a Raspberry Pi you might be using a linux.
So try to compile it(or install it with your default package manager) instead of pip installing.
This link would help.http://segfault.in/2010/03/paramiko-ssh-and-sftp-with-python/

Comment: pip should compile it as well (assuming there are parts that need to be compiled)

Comment: I did this but I still get the same error, any more suggestions why?